# Difference between INT 0X80 and SYSCALL

Tags: x86, system-call

The **SYSCALL** instruction is said to be the 64-bit version of **INT 0X80**, however it's still possible to use the latter in 64-bit code (although [strace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) decodes it wrong because of the 64-bit ABI I guess) which usually goes through a ["legacy entry"](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e7d0c41ecc2e372a81741a30894f556afec24315/arch/x86/entry/entry_64_compat.S#L267). But there's something I don't quite understand, why is the *SYSCALL* instruction faster?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is that `syscall` has less overhead than `int 0x80`.

For more details on why this is the case, see the accepted answer to [Intel x86 vs x64 system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168822/intel-x86-vs-x64-system-call), where a nearly identical question was asked:

> I'm told that syscall is lighter and faster than generating a software interrupt. Why it is faster on x64 than x86, and can I make a system call on x64 using int 80h?

See also:

- [Intel P6 vs P7 system call performance](https://lkml.org/lkml/2002/12/9/13)

  - this email thread discusses the observed slowdown on certain Intel CPUs caused by the overhead associated with `int 0x80`
- [Sysenter Based System Call Mechanism in Linux 2.6](http://articles.manugarg.com/systemcallinlinux2_6.html)

  > It was found out that this software interrupt method [int 0x80] was much slower on Pentium IV processors. To solve this issue, Linus implemented an alternative system call mechanism to take advantage of SYSENTER/SYSEXIT instructions provided by all Pentium II+ processors.
- [The Linux kernel, 4.6 Sysenter and the vsyscall page (2003)](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-4.html)

  > It has been observed that a 2 GHz Pentium 4 was much slower than an 850 MHz Pentium III on certain tasks, and that this slowness is caused by the very large overhead of the traditional `int 0x80` interrupt on a Pentium 4. Some models of the i386 family do have faster ways to enter the kernel. On Pentium II there is the `sysenter` instruction. Also AMD has a `syscall` instruction.